# MySQL: Returning a count of objects matching all tags

Tags: mysql, sql, aggregate-functions

I have a situation where I need to match an objects to multiple tags simultaneously so that results set is "narrowed down" to match all tags. I've found the following MySQL query for this:

```
  SELECT * 
    FROM OBJECTS o
    JOIN OBJECTSTAGS ot ON ot.object_id = o.id
    JOIN TAGS t ON t.id = ot.tag_id
   WHERE t.name IN ('tag1','tag2')
GROUP BY o.id
  HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT t.name) = 2
```

... where 2 is the number of tags being matched. It works fine.

However, I need the query to return a count of the objects instead of the objects themselves. This query seems to confuse itself if I add `COUNT(*)` to the `SELECT`. I'm hesitant to return just the ids for example and do a PHP count of them because they could add up to a very large number. I would therefore like MySQL to return the count.

Could anyone suggest a good way to do this? Breaking it into two queries would be acceptable.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: To be clear - you want a count of all the objects that match, or a count per object?  An example of your expected result would help.

Comment: @OMG Ponies: Count of the objects, one number only as the result. For example: 550 objects in total matching those tags.

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php; this might help.

EDIT: whoops thought this was php, this is irrelevent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
  SELECT COUNT(o.*) AS numObjects
    FROM OBJECTS o
   WHERE EXISTS (SELECT NULL
                   FROM OBJECTSTAGS ot 
                   JOIN TAGS t ON t.id = ot.tag_id
                              AND t.name IN ('tag1','tag2')
                  WHERE ot.object_id = o.id)
```

Comment: Pure genius. I dont know how you do it but keep doing it :)

Comment: +1 nice! But would this count all objects which have tag1 **OR** tag2? Is there a way to have them count those that have BOTH?

Comment: @Konerak: Yes - add the `GROUP BY` and `HAVING` clause provided in the OP's question into the EXISTS query.